# issue loading js scripts with history.js

Tags: jquery, html, history.js

Currently trying at add ajax to a site, after much reading I discovered that history.js covers all the areas i require.
However try as I might I cannot seem to get the jquery files loading when the pages are called via ajax.

I have downloaded the history.js & ajaxify-html5.js files, moved the 's to inside the #content div on each page where the content is loaded, but still not getting the js working on the dynamically called pages.

All the HTML is valid, here is a brief overview of the code (stripped down):

```
<header>
<title>Site Name</title>
</header>
<body>
<section id="container">
<div id="ajax-page">
*Content here*
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Standard ajaxify-html5.js with minor changes:

```
// Wait for Document
$(function(){
    // Prepare Variables
    var
        /* Application Specific Variables */
        contentSelector = '#ajax-page,article:first,.article:first,.post:first',
        $content = $(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
        contentNode = $content.get(0),
        $menu = $('#menu,#nav,nav:first,.nav:first').filter(':first'),
        activeClass = 'active selected current youarehere',
        activeSelector = '.active,.selected,.current,.youarehere',
        menuChildrenSelector = '> li,> ul > li',
        /* Application Generic Variables */
        $body = $(document.body),
        rootUrl = History.getRootUrl();
```

Any idea's on what I'm doing wrong?
Would be very grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue caused by reloading the main nav with the ajax, recoded the page so the nav stays intact and this fixes the issue.

Comment: great you answered your own question. Don't forget to check back later and mark it accepted so that everybody knows your problem was solved!